# how do i make the bones this way?

Tags: modeling, animation, bones

[enter link description here](https://youtu.be/kuiaLeupeG4)

[image]

how do i do this with the exact model im working with...image below is not the model im working with...im working with the same model but diferent way...video attached.

Comment: these are bones that are customed, you can bring them back to the octahedral appearance but anyway they are set to work in the game engine, they won't help to animate in Blender, you need to use the armature you showed in your previous question. By the way, if someone answered to your previous question, mark it as correct

Comment: Hi. Please use a title that matches the content of the question. It should be descriptive but succinct, unique and identifying, summarizing the issue so that anyone searching for a similar problem is likely to find it. Remove anything superfluous, avoid using words like "*this*", "*help with*", "*issue*" or "*question about*", instead describe what "it" is. Remember, your title is the first thing potential visitors see, answers you get depend heavily on how insightful it is. See [*What is the problem of asking “How do I do this?"*](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2449)